# How to mirror shape keys

Tags: shape-keys

I have shape keys that deform one part of the mesh and want to do the same on the right.

[image: Left side of the mesh deformed, shape key active]
Left side of the mesh deformed, shape key active

[image: Right side of the mesh, not deformed]
Right side of the mesh, not deformed

Can I mirror deform_belly_b.L into deform_belly_b.R so that it does the exact same thing on the right side?

Comment: Create symmetrical shapekeys, duplicate them, then use the vertex group as an influence for Left or Right. You can't use this method if you created your shapekey assymetrically, you'd have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this.
Select deform_belly_b.L And set it to 1 (make sure rest of the shapekeys are at o).
Then press the arrow key below the '-' button , and select duplicate from mix.
Now select the new generated shapekey again press the down arrow key and select Mirror shape key.